# How to get a list of jboss users over the CLI client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, command-line-interface, jboss7.x

I have not found anything suitable in the [Management API ref](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+API+reference) or the [CLI guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommandLineInterface).

My guess for retrieving the users of the management realm would have been

```
ls core-service=management/security-realm=ManagementRealm/authentication=properties
```

but it returns nothing. I do have a management user though.

I am using Jboss-7.1.1.Final

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your users are stored in the properties file then it is not possible to obtain a listing of them using the management interface.

Adding identity management operations including listing and modifying users is something being considered for a later release.

Comment: Thanks Darran - a no is a valid answer too :) just one more thing though - could you please link your sources? I found it quite hard to get an overview of things possible and impossible with the JBoss CLI, so a good resource would be appreciated.

Comment: My 'source' is I wrote the properties file based realm so know I never exposed any operations to list the actual users it contains ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Open the below file with notepad and find the list of users:

```
$HOME_wildfly-Final\standalone\configuration\mgmt-groups.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `help --commands` to see commands availabe in your current context.

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] help --commands
Commands available in the current context:
attachment                              deployment-info                         run-batch

batch                                   deployment-overlay                      security disable-http-auth-http-server

cd                                      echo                                    security disable-http-auth-management

clear                                   echo-dmr                                security disable-sasl-management

command                                 for                                     security disable-ssl-http-server

command-timeout                         grep                                    security disable-ssl-management

connect                                 help                                    security enable-http-auth-http-server

connection-info                         history                                 security enable-http-auth-management

data-source                             if                                      security enable-sasl-management

deploy                                  jdbc-driver-info                        security enable-ssl-http-server

deployment deploy-cli-archive           ls                                      security enable-ssl-management

deployment deploy-file                  module                                  security reorder-sasl-management

deployment deploy-url                   patch apply                             set

deployment disable                      patch history                           shutdown

deployment disable-all                  patch info                              try

deployment enable                       patch inspect                           undeploy

deployment enable-all                   pwd                                     unset

deployment info                         quit                                    version

deployment list                         read-attribute                          xa-data-source

deployment undeploy                     read-operation
deployment undeploy-cli-archive         reload
To read a description of a specific command execute 'help <command name>'.
```

So to answer to your question you can't list jboss users over CLI Client, you can see in

> EAP_HOME/domain/configuration/mgmt-users.properties or
> application-users.properties